# Google oauth authorization error. 'Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch'

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

why I am getting this error when i try to authorize my Oauth app.

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy. \n\nIf you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Learn more
Request Details 
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/
```

The redirect URL `https://localhost:8080` is registered in the google cloud console but still, i am getting this error.

Python file

```py
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secrets.json',
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'])

flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
```

client_secrets.json

```json
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "$id",
    "project_id": "youtube-constant-update",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "$secret",
    "redirect_uris": ["https://localhost:8080"]
  }
}
```

Any type of support/help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**http** and **https** are different URIs. You registered **https** but the error message is for **http**. URIs include the scheme.

Register the Redirect URI `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: I tried but keep getting error : Invalid Redirect: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org).

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail - create a new question. In your question include where you are running the code. You cannot use **localhost** for backends. You can use **localhost** when developing on your desktop (the web browser is running on the same machine as your code).

Comment: I am already have another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559158/oauth-02-authentication-give-error-400-invalid-request, and I am running the code from the localhost

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail - You do not state where you are running this code nor do you show the code nor how you configure the OAuth Client. Details help solve problems.