# OAuth.02 Authentication give Error 400 : Invalid Request

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube, google-developers-console

I am trying to test the youtube live stream API that I have downloaded from Github to be able to use it in one of my projects

in the following the URL for the GitHub repository

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples

I have followed the steps to get OAuth Client ID and Secret and add them to my code but I keep getting the error

[image]

Comment: The error says that app owner should configure the `redirect_uri`. But `redirect_uri` is used for a user auth in a browser. However, you probably would like to use a Client Credentials flow, I guess.

Comment: I tried to add redirect url and I am getting an error : Invalid Origin: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)., and I am trying to test using localhost on port 8080